# want to use protractor- perf in my scripts to assess the performance

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, protractor

I want to test the performance of a webpage using a protractor(protractor- perf). So how should I proceed with that? I tried "https://github.com/axemclion/protractor-perf" this article also. But it did not work for me. I have protractor framework(using Webstrom IDE) which I use for running scripts. I want to integrate my framework with protractor-perf so that I can use in my scripts to assess the performance of the page.

I am not very good at coding. I have just started doing it. So if the answer to the question can be given on a beginners level, then that will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try using the [Resource Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API) or [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API)

Comment: thanks, I will go through these articles.